# Count the number of rows and back result if is greater than 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have try to display result only if content > 0

```
SELECT actors.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM `content_actors`
                  WHERE content_actors.actor = actors.record_id) AS getCount
FROM actors
```

If i try to add in query

```
WHERE getCount > 0
```

I will have error

> Unknown column 'getCount' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT actors.*,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM `content_actors` WHERE content_actors.actor = actors.record_id) AS getCount
FROM actors
HAVING getCount > 0;
```

This is a MySQL extension.

Assuming `actors.record_id` is unique (presumably a primary key), this could be written as:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) as getCount
FROM actors a JOIN
     content_actors ca
     ON ca.actor = a.record_id
GROUP BY a.record_id;  -- assumes this is unique/primary key
```

No filtering is needed, because the `JOIN` requires at least one match.

Comment: Yes HAVING getCount is working, but 2nd example does not work

 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'a.name';